# Reformat postcodes to include a space

Tags: mysql, postal-code

Is there a reliable process (using MySQL) to reformat UK postcodes which contain no spaces so that they do?

For example:

- `CM75GJ` -> `CM7 5GJ`
- `L269XR` -> `L26 9XR`
- `YO265TD` -> `YO26 5TD`

Comment: The last 3 digits before space? Is this what u asking?

Comment: Can you specify and algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [UK postal code formatting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Formatting) and assuming there are is no faulty input, this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE address SET postcode =
    SUBSTRING(postcode, 1, LEN(postcode)-3) + ' ' +
    SUBSTRING(postcode, LEN(postcode)-2, 3)
```

Comment: Swap LEN for CHAR_LENGTH in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @TheoF I'm unfamiliar with PostgreSQL but Googling a bit yes it sounds like that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, this worked for me (Canadian Postal Code):

```
...
UPPER(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(replace(postal_code, ' ', ''), 1, 3), ' ', SUBSTRING(replace(postal_code, ' ', ''), 4, 3)))
```